# SQL Azure Transient Fault with Data Access Application Block 6.0

Tags: azure-sql-database, enterprise-library

In one of our application, we are using Enterprise Library 6.0 data access block. We are initializing Database object as

```
DatabaseFactory.SetDatabaseProviderFactory(new DatabaseProviderFactory());
Database database = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase();
```

We required to set **SqlAzureTransientErrorDetectionStrategy and/or RetryPolicy** for above database object.

Is there any way to accomplish above with Data Access Application Block & Transient Fault Handling Application Block for Windows Azure SQL?

I know we can achieve it with ReliableSqlConnection but could not find any resource for Data Access Application Block & Transient Fault Handling Application Block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE START**

I'm adding full class implementation here so that it can be useful to other user as well.

```
public class SqlAzureDatabase : SqlDatabase
{
    public RetryPolicy _retryPolicy { get; set; }

    public SqlAzureDatabase(string connectionString, RetryPolicy retryPolicy)
        : base(connectionString)
    {
        this._retryPolicy = retryPolicy;
    }

    protected override DatabaseConnectionWrapper GetWrappedConnection()
    {
        return new DatabaseConnectionWrapper(GetNewOpenConnection());
    }

    private DbConnection GetNewOpenConnection()
    {
        SqlConnection connection = null;
        try
        {
            connection = base.CreateConnection() as SqlConnection;
            if (connection != null)
            {
                connection.OpenWithRetry(this._retryPolicy);
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            if (connection != null && connection.State != System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed)
                connection.Close();

            throw;
        }

        return connection;
    }

    public override int ExecuteNonQuery(DbCommand command)
    {
        using (DatabaseConnectionWrapper wrapper = GetOpenConnection())
        {
            PrepareCommand(command, wrapper.Connection);
            return DoExecuteNonQueryWithRetry(command);
        }
    }

    private int DoExecuteNonQueryWithRetry(DbCommand command)
    {
        if (command == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("command");

        SqlCommand sqlCommand = command as SqlCommand;

        if (sqlCommand != null)
        {
            int rowsAffected = sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQueryWithRetry(this._retryPolicy);
            return rowsAffected;
        }

        return 0;
    }

    public override IDataReader ExecuteReader(DbCommand command)
    {
        using (DatabaseConnectionWrapper wrapper = GetOpenConnection())
        {
            PrepareCommand(command, wrapper.Connection);
            IDataReader realReader = DoExecuteReaderWithRetry(command, CommandBehavior.Default);
            return CreateWrappedReader(wrapper, realReader);
        }
    }

    private IDataReader DoExecuteReaderWithRetry(DbCommand command, CommandBehavior cmdBehavior)
    {
        if (command == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("command");

        SqlCommand sqlCommand = command as SqlCommand;

        if (sqlCommand != null)
        {
            IDataReader reader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReaderWithRetry(_retryPolicy);
            return reader;
        }

        return null;
    }

    public override object ExecuteScalar(DbCommand command)
    {
        using (DatabaseConnectionWrapper wrapper = GetOpenConnection())
        {
            PrepareCommand(command, wrapper.Connection);
            return DoExecuteScalarWithRetry(command);
        }
    }

    private object DoExecuteScalarWithRetry(IDbCommand command)
    {
        if (command == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("command");

        SqlCommand sqlCommand = command as SqlCommand;

        if (sqlCommand != null)
        {
            object returnValue = sqlCommand.ExecuteScalarWithRetry(this._retryPolicy);
            return returnValue;
        }

        return null;
    } 
}
```

SqlAzureDatabase class in action as explained below.

```
Database database = new SqlAzureDatabase(connectionString, retryPolicy);
```

**UPDATE END**

---

I had similar need, ended up creating an extension of `SqlDatabase` class and overriding `GetWrappedConnection` method as:

```
protected override DatabaseConnectionWrapper GetWrappedConnection()
{
            return new DatabaseConnectionWrapper(GetNewOpenConnection());
}
```

GetNewOpenConnection() is a private method

```
private DbConnection GetNewOpenConnection()
 {
            SqlConnection connection = null;
            try
            {
                connection = CreateConnection() as SqlConnection;
                if(connection != null)
                {
                    connection.OpenWithRetry(this._retryPolicy);
                }

                //instrumentationProvider.FireConnectionOpenedEvent();
            }
            catch
            {
                if (connection != null)
                    connection.Close();

                throw;
            }

            return connection;
  }
```

Download the `SqlAzureDatabase` class @ http://1drv.ms/SJft8o. It was primarily done to support Federation but you can modify it or just use the basic constructor which will take care of injecting retry policy

```
public SqlAzureDatabase(string connectionString)
           : this(connectionString, FederationType.None, null, null, null)
{
}
```

Comment: I think Transient Errors can also happen when executing commands not just when opening Connection, so you would also need to override usual methods like ExecuteReader, ExecuteScalar etc.

Comment: @NandipMakwana The link to the class code is broken. Can you post it to github as a gist so that it can live forever?